# Adding watermark and pricing to images in a folder dynamically with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, batch-processing

I have a task where I need to treat multiple images in a folder, adding watermark to each image + adding a price within a price tag.

I can apply the watermark and price tag to the images using recorded actions along with Image processor, and get a new folder with all the images with proper watermark and price tag, independent of their size.

The problem here is how I will be adding the prices, I have learned to use variables and datasets with photoshop, but the problem is:

- How to use them to act on multiple images in a folder to add the
  price in the specified price tag location on the image based on CSV file where I can provide the name of the image and its price? Is this even possible with photoshop?
- Can I use the variables when recording the action and automate the process with the Image Processor?

**P.S**: I am not a graphic designer, and I do not have much experience with photoshop. I am just trying to get this task done.

Comment: Why not write a script? Although generally this is a job for imagemagic or graphics magic

Comment: @joojaa, Can you please provide some guidelines to help me out with this process? If you write an answer with some steps I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @joojaa I don't think a script is worth his time or the right call to achieve this. There are more in-software routes to take over scripting.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor to be honest imagemagik is simpler than either of your options

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options.

1. [Use Photoshop's Data-Driven Functions](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html)
2. [Use InDesign to import data](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html)

Both the links above have ample information for you to get started.

For a better walkthrough of a sample method for [Photoshop this link is good](http://www.richmediacs.com/user_manuals/RMCS_PS_Training/Using%20PS%20Variables/UsingVariablesInPS_EXTERNAL.html) or [InDesign this site covers it nicely](https://redokun.com/blog/data-merge-indesign).

[There is also a StackOverflow question that helps cover how to import the data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405903/how-to-load-csv-data-into-a-photoshop)

Personally I use InDesign at work. It is more robust and will be really easy to just set-up linked .psd to get your images in to work with.